# Apache HSTS exception for some virtual hosts

Tags: ssl, https, http-headers, apache-2.2

In the global config section for Apache 2.2.15, I have the following (per [recommendation](http://opentodo.net/2012/10/enable-http-strict-transport-security-in-apache-nginx/))

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;includeSubDomains" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>
```

I would like to add this header only when the request is NOT for a specific host (dev.host.com). **Which [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html) do I use to make *header add* occur only when not for a specific host?**

PS: The second part of this question has been [moved](https://serverfault.com/questions/633420/apache-configuration-redirect-using-only-redirect-not-rewrite).

Answer (score 5):

1. If you only include the IfModule directive in a VirtualHost Directive for x.x.x.x:443, then it will only apply to that VirtualHost, and there only apply to the https protocol.
2. You could try the  directive

   ```
   <If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'www.dev.domain.com'">
       <IfModule mod_headers.c>
           Header unset Strict-Transport-Security
           Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0;includeSubDomains"
       </IfModule>
   </If>
   ```

Comment: I could also only set the header for all hosts minus the one I don't want to set it for. I will check into this and report back.

Comment: I dont think it's possible to use `<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'www.dev.domain.com'">` in httpd.conf

Comment: It is valid... only in apache 2.4

Comment: Thanks, but the OP states it is Apache 2.2

Answer (score 1):

In Apache 2.2 you can probably play with something like bellow.

- Set an env to identify general case and exclude specific case:

  ```
  SetEnvIf HTTPS do_work_on_headers    
  SetEnvIf Host "^www.myexcludedhostname.tld$" !do_work_on_headers
  ```
- then conditionnally set headers:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;includeSubDomains" env=do_work_on_headers
  </IfModule>
  ```

Comment: This one should work for apache 2.2